# Add a check box for each row - display column tag

Tags: jsp

I want to add a check box at the start of each row. I tried adding it but its not working.

Can anyone please help.

```
<display:table decorator="com.Decorator" sort="external" style="text-align:left">
    <display:column property='checkbox' name='selectall'/>
    <display:column property="Address" title="Address" sortable="false" headerClass="sortable" style="min-width:80px"/>
    <display:column property="Name" title="Name" sortable="false" headerClass="sortable" style="min-width:120px"/>
    <display:column property="status" title="Status" sortable="false" headerClass="sortable" style="min-width:80px"/>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing to

```
<display:column style="min-width:20px">
    <input type="checkbox" /> 
</display:column>
```